# Odoo - redirect to external link without modifying source code

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

A friend of mine has an Odoo website linked to many other functionalities but that I don't think are relevant for the case. His problem is that he would like to change the URL of one of the button on its website to an external link. I looked around and can only see developper's solution and his eternal dev deprioritized it so he is a stuck. I looked around and saw the possibility to maybe change things on the website builder, what I did sequentially:

- activated developer mode
- went to "Website"
- Clicked "Modify" (or maybe "Edit" with the English settings) at the top right corner
- clicked on the button he wants to change the redirect link of
- a modal appears and then asks me for relative URL only

Is there any way, without going into the code, to make this modal accept absolute URL instead of relative ones
Thanks

Comment: That's the correct way.. The other solution coming to my mind is to write a module with more code. =)